# Analogue of Borel--Bott--Weil for General Equivariant Vector Bundles

Tags: rt.representation-theory, complex-geometry, flag-varieties, equivariant-cohomology

The [Borel--Bott--Weil Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Weil%E2%80%93Bott_theorem) gives the dimensions of the cohomology groups of the equivariant line bundles over flag manifolds. Does there exist an analogous result for general equivariant vector bundles over the flag varieties, or even just for complex projective $n$-space?

Comment: On flag variety any equivariant vector bundle is an iterated extension of line bundles. So, its Euler characteristic can be computed by applying BBW to the factors and summing up.

Comment: Could you give a reference for this?

Comment: It follows easily from the equivalence of the category of equivariant bundles and the category of representations of Borel subgroup, since Borel is solvable.

Comment: Bott's 1957 Annals article, well worth reading, analyzes the general $G/P$ situation, too.

Comment: @Sasha: But the category of Borel subgroup modules is semi-simple, so surely the only extensions of line bundles are direct sums of line bundles?

Comment: @user36087: Since a Borel subgroup is solvable, its module category is far from being semi-simple.

Comment: If instead we look at $G_0/L_0$ "the compact real form" of $G/H$, then is the module category of $L_0$ semi-simple?

Comment: Once you go to real groups like that, how are you going to study the coherent-sheaf cohomology groups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [article](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~jml/kostant61.pdf) Lie Algebra Cohomology and the Generalized Borel-Weil theorem by Kostant contains generalization of the BBW theorem to equivariant vector bundles over $G/P$ associated to a $G$-representation, where $P$ is a parabolic subgroup. Actually, it contains a bit more, since Kostant goes a long way with just a "Lie summand" that reappeared in kind of a different generalization of BBW via the Kostant cubic Dirac operator.

Answer (score 3):

In [this dissertation](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/bitstream/handle/10012/5421/alfaisal_thesis.pdf?sequence=1) you can find the complete proof of generalized Borel Weil theorem over $G/P$.

On the Representation Theory of
Semisimple Lie Groups
by
Faisal Al-Faisal

Comment: Thanks. One can find a complete proof in many places, even the original Kostant's article is quite complete and readable. But it is always nice to read a good distillation in a master thesis.